# Python: Conditional replacement where two DataFrames are equal (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have 2 DataFrames A and B (See below).
I want to update the NaNs from A.my_city with B.City WHERE A.my_zip == B.Zipcode.

How can I do this in a nice way using Pandas?

DataFrame A:

```
    my_city      my_zip      
0   Copenhagen   4000  
1   Amsterdam    2000 
2   NaN          4040    
3   NaN          5000
```

DataFrame B:

```
    City       Zipcode      
0   Lisboa       4040
1   London       5000 
2   Beijing      6000    
3   Hong Kong    5000   
4   New York     4040    
5   Istanbul     5000
```

Therefore, I want this result:

```
   my_city      my_zip      
0   Copenhagen   4000  
1   Amsterdam    2000 
2   Lisboa       4040    
3   London       5000
```

Thanks!

Comment: The description of what you want is a little different than your expected output.  Do you want to update the NaNs in A.my_city with the B.City values where the zipcodes match like your output?

Comment: It is a little odd your second df, you have duplicated zipcodes in your df, your result takes the first match